# Why does persisted? return true after ActiveRecord::Rollback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Example:

```
BillingProfile.transaction do
  if @billing_profile.save
    unless SomeService.do_something # returns false and rollback occurs
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end

@billing_profile.persisted? # Still return true, despite rollback
@billing_profile.id # Is set, despite rollback
```

Why wouldn't the state of @billing_profile reflect that the record was rolled back?

This is a problem since the record cannot be created after it has been rolled back.

Comment: what version of Rails are you using?  I can't remember what version I tried this when I was able to replicate your issue.  But I'm trying it now on rails 2 and 3.2 but I get a proper rollback.

Comment: Rails 4. I reported this as a bug in ActiveRecord which has now been fixed https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13744

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in ActiveRecord (Rails 4): https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13744

It has now been fixed.

Comment: I'm hitting this with rails 5.0.0.1 atm. I do `@model.save`, this raises a database error but still `@model.persisted?` returns `true`. Crazy. I'd think there would be a unit test for it.

Answer (score 0):

I got interested in how transactions work.  Your specific scenario is explained in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).  Quoting the docs

> transaction calls can be nested. By default, this makes all database
>   statements in the nested transaction block become part of the parent
>   transaction. For example, the following behavior may be surprising:
>
> ```
> User.transaction do
>   User.create(username: 'Kotori')
>   User.transaction do
>     User.create(username: 'Nemu')
>     raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> creates both “Kotori” and “Nemu”. Reason is the ActiveRecord::Rollback
>   exception in the nested block does not issue a ROLLBACK. Since these
>   exceptions are captured in transaction blocks, the parent block does
>   not see it and the real transaction is committed.
>
> In order to get a ROLLBACK for the nested transaction you may ask for
>   a real sub-transaction by passing requires_new: true. If anything goes
>   wrong, the database rolls back to the beginning of the sub-transaction
>   without rolling back the parent transaction. If we add it to the
>   previous example:
>
> ```
> User.transaction do
>   User.create(username: 'Kotori')
>   User.transaction(requires_new: true) do
>     User.create(username: 'Nemu')
>     raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> only “Kotori” is created. This works on MySQL and PostgreSQL. SQLite3
>   version >= '3.6.8' also supports it.
>
> Most databases don't support true nested transactions. At the time of
>   writing, the only database that we're aware of that supports true
>   nested transactions, is MS-SQL. Because of this, Active Record
>   emulates nested transactions by using savepoints on MySQL and
>   PostgreSQL. See dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/savepoint.html for
>   more information about savepoints.

Comment: Adding requires_new: true to the transaction didn't solve the issue for me. The id is still set and persisted? is still returning true. I also don't have nested transactions as in your example; there is only one transaction...